# How to copy to the UIPasteBoard from the Quick Actions menu without entering the app?

Tags: swift, 3dtouch, uipasteboard, quickaction, uiapplicationshortcutitem

Is it possible to directly copy a value from a shortcut item without entering the app? I want to do something similar to Apple's Calculator App:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of now, otherwise the user would not be able to figure out if anything happened or not.

And for the calculator app, when you tap copy result it opens the Calculator app and then copies the last result.

You can do somewhat similar by showing a view controller that shows result copied or something similar.